# How do you send a mousemove event from an iframe back to the parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mouseevent

Using jquery, how would I send an iframe's window mousemove events back to its parent, and the parent will see the event with the mouse coordinates mapped to it's own window? Both the iframe and parent are on the same domain.

Comment: What have you tried? jQuery needs to be included in the iFrame's source. You access the parent with top.document.

Comment: jquery is inside the source... I've added a mousemove event to a div inside the iframe, and those mousemove events need to be sent to the parent somehow. I'm implementing a draggable div in the parent window that has an iframe in it. Clicking the title bar starts the dragging, but you need to capture mousemove events in the window for it to work. When the mouse moves into the iframe, I lose mousemove events, and can no longer drag the div around.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by overlaying the iframe with an absolutely positioned transparent div. This way, the parent always gets the mousemove events.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this approach. One of the iframes that I was embedding required the microphone, so Flash opened a popup asking if it was okay to use it. The mouse click events were not reaching the popup, so I couldn't say "yes". Not sure why because the flash objects are getting them.