# Bubble up mousemove event on iframe to the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following code

```
<div onmousemove="myFunction()">
  <iframe src="www.someotherdomain.com"/>
</div>
```

I want `myFunction` to be executed when user moves his mouse over the iframe. Is it possible to bubble up the events on iframe to the parent element in cross domain scenario? How will I do this?

PS:-
I can't use the solution provided in

[Iframe obstructing the mousemove event from occuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18418467/iframe-obstructing-the-mousemove-event-from-occuring)

or

[How do you send a mousemove event from an iframe back to the parent using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608474/how-do-you-send-a-mousemove-event-from-an-iframe-back-to-the-parent-using-jquery)

because I want the user to be able to interact with the content in the iframe.

Comment: I am 99.999% sure you are SOL

Comment: Not sure what you're after. http://jsfiddle.net/L5bsxykw/ ?

Comment: this is mouseover event which is generated on div itself. which works fine. But mousemove events are generated on the iframe and NOT propagated to the div

Comment: What do you actually want to _achieve_ with this? Why do you need to know what the user does with their mouse in an iframe document from a different domain?

Comment: I have a session timeout on my main site which will logout the user if he is inactive for a certain time. This iFrame takes up a large portion in my website where user can spend a lot of time doing things. I don't want the user to be timed out since he is inactive on the other parts of the website.

Answer (score 2):

I can see only one way.

Disable the session timer when mousing into the iframe and enable it when mousing out.

To do this, add a margin in the div and use mouseenter plus mouseleave from the outer div and vice versa on the way out.

If the window loses focus you may also want to enable the timer

Comment: This will not log out the user if the user is actually idle on the iFrame

Comment: I know - if you have no access to the Iframe content then that is the best you can do